# How do I access a component's HTML outside an Angular v6 app?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created a component outside app using the Angular CLI (in src folder)

```
../src> ng g c test
```

And added the component import in `app-modules.ts`

I'm not able to access the `test.html` file separately (I want to execute the code in the `ngOnInit` method of test.ts) as below
`http://localhost:4200/<<context_path>>/test.html`

I even created HTML and a JavaScript file and tried to access, however that didn't work.

Kindly let me know is it possible to access the HTML?

Thanks for the response. Below the screenshot
[Application screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmdzw.png)

i want to access like http://localhost:4200/test.html

Comment: you should be able to access it via JS calls from the component's HTML - i doubt that you could do it from the component.ts file

Comment: @AIqbalRaj How would you go about accessing it from HTML? In the TS file, all you need is access to `document` -- which you have -- and it's trivial method calls from there.

Comment: your test.html file should be in the assets folder - this will ensure that when you build the solution, you get it also. if you can create a minimal stackblitz for your example, i can try to show hoe i would do it...

Answer (score 0):

this called bad approach you shouldn't create `components` out of *src folder* i don't mean by that is not gonna work but not recommended to do that *src folder* excite to gather all your project `component` to make it easy to access and sharing the data between them.

**alternative solution 1:** you can delete the `component` you made out of `src` folder and recreate another one in `app` folder or simply move the `component` *files/folder* in the `app` that's the correct approach.
then you can access to it from any other `component` in your app by `import` it in `ts` *file*

**alternative solution 2:** if you want just to *sharing data* or executing method/function that maybe shared by two `components` that holds some data you can use `services` or `event binding`.

**alternative solution 3:** if your problem with `routes` and you want to `naviagte` to this `test.html` for recommended approach firstly move it inside the `app` *folder* like *alternative solution 1* then use `routes` and it's `config` to create a `route` for this `component`.

**notice:** you couldn't `inject` only `html` file inside `angular components` it must has his own `ts` file that holds the `component config` `@Component({...})` that's how angular knows that's `component` excite and how to `inject` it to other `components`.